# Remove all elements matching a predicate from a list in-place

Tags: python

How can I remove all elements matching a predicate from a list ***IN-PLACE***?

```py
T = TypeVar("T")

def remove_if(a: list[T], predicate: Callable[[T], bool]):
    # TODO: Fill this in.

# Test:
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
remove_if(a, lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
assert(a == [1, 3, 5])
```

**The answer should be O(N); not O(N^2).**

Here is a similar question but it does not require ***IN-PLACE*** removal: [Removing an element from a list based on a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866343/removing-an-element-from-a-list-based-on-a-predicate)

In Rust this is [`Vec::retain()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain). In C++ it is [`std::remove_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) (plus `erase()`).

Is there an equivalent in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In-place modification of Python lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51804790/in-place-modification-of-python-lists)

Comment: I don't think you can achieve O(n) with in place operations in python. [Removing a item is O(n)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). Why do you have this in place constraint? Or maybe use `a[:] = [x for x in a if x%2==0]`?

Comment: Sure you can. See my answer.

Comment: I like your `a[:]` answer too - I forgot you can assign lists like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing an element from a list based on a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866343/removing-an-element-from-a-list-based-on-a-predicate) Specifically look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866343/removing-an-element-from-a-list-based-on-a-predicate/1866977#1866977 (This is the same question you've linked in your question)

Comment: That answer is O(N^2). Please don't suggest questions as duplicate that *I've explicitly said are not duplicate!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick using the standard algorithm. It does unnecessarily copy elements to themselves before the first failure of the predicate, so you may want to add a `find()` at the start of the loop (see the "Possible Implementation" for C++'s `std::remove_if()`). It should still be pretty fast though and that doesn't affect the complexity which is O(N).

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def remove_if(lst: list[T], predicate: Callable[[T], bool]):
    i = 0
    for element in lst:
        if not predicate(element):
            lst[i] = element
            i += 1
    del lst[i:]
```

Edit: @mozway's answer is a lot simpler and probably O(N) too. You would need to benchmark to see which is actually faster because his probably isn't in-place in memory terms (though it is in-place in logical terms).

```
a[:] = [x for x in a if x%2==0]
```

Comment: I see, you're reusing the list and overwriting items, I thought you meant deleting the items one by one. Yes, in this case both approaches should have a similar timing.